# RabbitMQ single exchange and single queue with multiple routing keys

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to use BasicGet to retrieve only messages that match the Channel's Exchange/Queue/RoutingKey combination.

An example of our routing keys is

```
Development:STACK_1_WEBSERVER_V2:1:2.9.0.0
```

The trouble I am having is that the Routing Key is being completely ignored and all messages no matter what the specified routing key are available via BasicGet.

I am using a Direct exchange. I though Direct was enough, I do not need the ability to Wildcard the routing keys that you get with Topic exchanges.

Is a Direct Exchange and Routing Key solution supposed to work with BasicGet?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A direct exchange and routing keys is enough although your getter is pulling from a queue which has messages with multiple routing keys. You will need to setup separate queues for each getter that will want it's own group of messages.

This isn't a difference between `basic.get` and `basic.consume` in AMQP.

The exchange type and routing key doesn't matter at the time you are pulling the message from the queue, the message has already been routed to a queue.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So routing keys are not to be used to route messages within a single key, Correct? What are they for then?

Comment: Routing keys are used to tell RabbitMQ how to handle a message published to an exchange. The server will match the routing key with the queue's bind key and depending on the type of exchange decide how to handle the message.

Comment: What is meant by "depending on the type of exchange decide how to handle the message". Sounds like the routing key is part of the data used when deciding what message will be returned on a BasicGet when the queue is bound to that routing key.

Comment: We have clearly misunderstood Routing Keys. So can you just confirm that they are simply used as a way of RabbitMq working out what queue to ADD the message to when you Publish and that dequeueing a message is simply a read from a queue that does not care at all about the routing key. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally l thought Routing keys would be able to say route message to same queue and same exchange but have different consumers based on the routing key .But from deep searching it seems it doesn't work that way ...
All consumers bounded to a queue will just consume the messages in a round robin fashion .